# use RatingBar in dialog

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am trying to use a RatingBar like this.

```
private RatingBar ratingBar;
TextView submitTv;
int rate;

public RateDialog(){
    rate  = 0;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rate, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
    submitTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rate_textview_submit);

    submitTv.setOnClickListener(this);
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.rate_textview_submit:
            sendResult(INT_RATING_CODE,rate );
            getDialog().dismiss();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
    //rate  = (int)rating;
    rate = (int) ratingBar.getRating();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+String.valueOf(rate),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="2.0"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_grey_transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_semitransparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rate_textview_submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, I can't get the RatingBar to respond to inputs.Even after trying to use the toast in onRatingChanged() the toast does not fire.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try removing `ClickListener` from your `TextView` and check if it solves your problem or not.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani no it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

This should be false.